# To list the specific number of rows <li>

Tags: css

I would like to sort the list of categories to four lines.

Thank you for response

My css code:

```
    ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MOUM.png)

Comment: There's not enough information in your question for us to get you a good answer. Can you try explaining more exactly what you are trying to do, what have you tried so far, what errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #676767;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>rubriky</li>
  <li>A B C D E F G H I</li>

</ul>
```